# How to do this without 'distinct': Select Distinct(x) From x Left Join y Where y.attr = true

Tags: spring, jpa, criteria, criteria-api, spring-data-jpa

I'm stuck in a query, I'm using Spring Data JPA, JpaRepository and JpaSpecificationExecutor. So I have to use `Predicate`s from `CriteriaBuilder`.

At the moment I simply do:

```
Specifications<MyEntity> spec = Specifications.where(MySpec.isTrue());
List<MyEntity> myEntities = myRepository.findAll(spec);
```

where MySpec.isTrue() is:

```
public static Specification<MyEntity> isTrue() {
    return new Specification<MyEntity>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            SetJoin<MyEntity, JoinEntity> j = root.join(MyEntity.joinEntities, JoinType.LEFT);  
            return cb.isTrue(j.get(JoinEntity_.attr));
        }
    };
}
```

So this will of course result in this SQL:

```
SELECT e.* FROM MyEntity e
  LEFT OUTER JOIN JoinEntity j ON j.myEntityId = e.id
  WHERE j.attr = true
```

But I'm only interested in the unique set of `MyEntity`s. So in JPQL I'd write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(e) FROM MyEntity e
  LEFT JOIN e.joinEntities j
  WHERE j.attr = true
```

Right now my solution is:

```
List<MyEntity> myEntities = myRepository.findAll(spec);
Set<MyEntity> entitiesSet = new HashSet<MyEntity>(myEntities);
```

There must be a nicer way ;)

How does it work with `CriteriaBuilder` (and `JpaSpecificationExecutor`)?

---

### The solution(s):

The first idea was a simple distinct:

```
public static Specification<MyEntity> isTrue() {
    return new Specification<MyEntity>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            SetJoin<MyEntity, JoinEntity> j = root.join(MyEntity.joinEntities, JoinType.LEFT);
            query.distinct(true); // <<-- HERE  
            return cb.isTrue(j.get(JoinEntity_.attr));
        }
    };
}
```

This works but kinda destroys the sense of those small Specification pieces. So I came up with a solution using a subquery. It may take some additional time, but for me it doesn't matter at the moment:

```
public static Specification<MyEntity> isTrue() {
    return new Specification<MyEntity>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            Subquery<JoinEntity> subquery = query.subquery(JoinEntity.class);
            Root<JoinEntity> subRoot = subquery.from(JoinEntity.class);
            subquery.select(subRoot);
            subquery.where(cb.isTrue(subRoot.get(JoinEntity_.attr)));
            subquery.groupBy(subRoot.get(JoinEntity_.myEntity));

            return cb.exists(subquery);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`CriteriaQuery.distinct(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#distinct%28boolean%29)

Comment: so can i simply put `query.distinct(true)` inside the `toPredicate` method? **EDIT:** IT WORKS! :)

Comment: I guess so. I'm not familiar with this additional layer on top of the already ugly Criteria API, but I guess so. Quite strange for a method named `toPredicate()` to alter the select clause of a query, but it should work, I guess. Why don't you use JPQL for such static queries. JPQL is so much easier to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at JpaRepository with JpaSpecificationExecutor. It provides functionality like `findAll` and `findOne`, but you can also deliver some of these `Specification`s, which then provide the `WHERE` part of the query. Basically we use this for selective filters: **Example:** If the user enables *'show deleted items'* we will include this one specification in the chain. If the user also selects some other filter, we will chain those specs. **Have a look:** http://blog.springsource.org/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: That's why I find this solution strange. Calling distinct() on the query causes a side effect on the select clause in addition to creating and returning the where clause. It shouldn't be done there. But I'm not sure it can be done elsewhere, so maybe the API is just badly designed, or doesn't support every case in a clean way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm right now looking for another solution... I'm thinking about doing a subquery to find all the matching `JoinEntity`s with distinct on `JoinEntity.myEntityId`. And then use JOIN. What do you think?

Comment: I think that if your current query does what you want, there's no reason to replace it by a more complex one.

Comment: Yeah, it does what i want, but as you can imagine those `Specification` snippets should provide common functionality. So maybe this snippet should get used somewhere else. So it's better to have the subquery solution, if it works. Right now I have `SELECT j FROM JoinEntity j WHERE j.attr = true GROUP BY j.myEntityId = ?`. Now I have just to find out how to join it ;)

Comment: I've now a solution via subquery, i'll post it in my top post